# Yocto dnf error in do_roofs

Tags: yocto-project

I am trying to compile boot.scr from boot.cmd in Yocto "sumo", then adding it to the rootfs image.

In `/meta-myrepo/recipes-bootscript/bootscript/my-bootscript_1.0.bb` I have:

```
DESCRIPTION = "U-boot boot script"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

DEPENDS = "u-boot-mkimage-native"

SRC_URI += "file://boot.cmd"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
        mkimage -A arm -T script -C none -n "Boot script" -d "${WORKDIR}/boot.cmd" boot.scr
}

do_install() {
        install -d ${D}boot/
        install -m 0644 boot.scr ${D}boot/
}

FILES_${PN} += "/boot"
FILES_${PN} += "/boot/boot.scr"
```

When I run: `bitbake my-bootscript` it runs ok
But when I run: `bitbake fsl-image-gui` I always get the error:

```
ERROR: fsl-image-gui-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Could not invoke dnf. 
Command '/home/user/var-fsl-yocto/build_xwayland/tmp/work/imx8mm_var_dart-poky-linux/fsl-image-gui/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf -y -c ... locale-base-en-gb' returned 1:
Added oe-repo repo from /home/user/var-fsl-yocto/build_xwayland/tmp/work/imx8mm_var_dart-poky-linux/fsl-image-gui/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:02 ago on Mon 22 Apr 2019 10:55:32 PM UTC.
No match for argument: my-bootscript
Error: Unable to find a match
```

Comment: Try to add the following in the bottom of your recipe: `PACKAGES = "${PN}"`